# Center and scale an arbitrary image to fill a div

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a container div of unknown size*. I want to fill it with an image of unknown size such that the image completely fills the div, maintaining the aspect ratio.

Then I want to center the image so that the cropped parts are at the edges.

I also need a way to ensure that the container's padding doesn't show any of the image.

*If it helps, the container's size isn't really unknown. It's a Bootstrap column so I can compute the width if I need to.

**Solution**

These styles did the trick:

```
background: url(...) no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
background-position: center center;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
```

Comment: here is a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Lwaekyyx/3/

Comment: Thanks, but that image is not centered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be easily achieved using a background image. After you've specified it as you'd like, just add the following CSS to your container to make the background certainly *cover* its container, while keeping the aspect ratio:

**CSS code**

```
.container {
    background-size: cover;
}
```

This will *not* take maximum size into consideration, and will stretch the image beyond its native resolution, resulting in potential blurring.

Comment: Thanks, that worked perfectly. I'll update my question with the full solution I used.